# How to use dynamic connectionstring in layered aspnetcore 2.1 project?

Tags: postgresql

My team built a project , such that, there is a master db, which consists list of accounts. db is postgresql. Each account has its own connectionstring. Therefore there are number of customer databases which is equal to number of accounts. I published project on iis, then I saw but a big problem.

Lets assume three accounts,

```
Account A -> having dbA
Account B -> having dbB
Account C -> having dbC
```

Suppose account A logined first, then account B logined second, then account c logined third. If account a tries to save a company, it uses the account C's connection string,the company record is saved in dbC , which is so bad :( I am trying to find solution but I could not be able to do it. I prepared a simple project+db, the project can be downloaded from [here](http://eticaret.turkalpkucur.com/projectanddb.rar).